# Is that any single word or just a phrase for 'could not care less'?

Tags: synonyms

I need a shorter version of 'could not care less'.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on context, but "indifferent" or "apathetic" convey a similar meaning.

**Edited to add citations:**

Definition of "couldn't care less" is "Be completely indifferent"
(couldn't care less. (n.d.) Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. (2015). Retrieved March 5 2018 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/couldn%27t+care+less)

Synonym of "indifferent" is "apathetic":
(indifferent. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014). Retrieved March 5 2018 from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/indifferent)

Comment: citations for both please.

Answer (score 0):

could not care less = [**lackadaisical**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lackadaisical)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is "uninterested" - see [uninterested at dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uninterested).

This is not to be confused with [disinterested](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disinterested).